# Converting Legacy SQL Flatten function to Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following written in `#LegacySQL`:

```
   SELECT
      customer_email,
      submitted_at,
      title,
      answers.choices.labels answer_choices,
      answers.number score,
      answers.boolean true_false,
      metadata.platform device_type
    FROM
      (FLATTEN([test-test:sample.responses], answers)) resp
      LEFT JOIN [test-test:sample.forms] forms
    ON resp.answers.field.id = forms.id
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

It's returning the results as I want them, like so:

```
+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
|  customer_email  |      submitted_at       |                           title                            |   answer_choices   | score | true_false | device_type |
+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | How would you rate this product?                           |                    |    10 |            | other       |
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Delivery           |       |            | other       |
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | What other product(s) would you like to see us make?       | Additional Colors  |       |            | other       |
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | What other product(s) would you like to see us make?       | Additional Designs |       |            | other       |
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | What color(s) would you want to see?                       | Green              |       |            | other       |
+------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to convert to BigQuery `StandarSQL`, and I put together the following:

```
SELECT
  customer_email,
  submitted_at,
  title,
  answers.choices.labels answer_choices,
  answers.number score,
  answers.boolean true_false,
  metadata.platform device_type
FROM
`sample.responses` resp, unnest(answers) answers
LEFT JOIN `sample.forms` forms
ON answers.field.id  = forms.id
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Unfortunately, it's returning it as records like so:

```
+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
|  customer_email  |      submitted_at       |        landed_at        |                           title                            |   answer_choices   | score | true_false | device_type |
+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | 2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC | What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us? | Delivery           | null  | null       | other       |
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | 2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC | What other product(s) would you like to see us make?       | Additional Colors  | null  | null       | other       |
|                  |                         |                         |                                                            | Additional Designs |       |            |             |
| myname@gmail.com | 2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC | 2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC | What color(s) would you want to see?                       | Green              | null  | null       | other       |
+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+-------------+
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: is `answers.choices.labels` repeated (an array)?

Comment: Yes? I believe so

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that legacy SQL performs a `LEFT JOIN` with arrays when flattening them, whereas standard SQL's comma operator performs a regular `JOIN`. If you use `LEFT JOIN` when unnesting an array, you'll receive a row in the output (with `NULL` for the element's value) when the array is empty, whereas if you use a regular `JOIN`, the row will be omitted. This is akin to how joins between tables work as well. See the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#removing_repetition_with_flatten) for more details on the semantics.

What I think you want for your query is to use a `LEFT JOIN` between the table and the `answers` array:

```
SELECT
  customer_email,
  submitted_at,
  title,
  answer.choices.labels AS answer_choices,
  answer.number score,
  answer.boolean true_false,
  metadata.platform device_type
FROM
  `sample.responses` resp
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(resp.answers) AS answer
LEFT JOIN `sample.forms` forms
ON answer.field.id  = forms.id
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

If you want to flatten `answer.choices.labels` as well, you can change it to:

```
SELECT
  customer_email,
  submitted_at,
  title,
  label AS answer_choices,
  answer.number score,
  answer.boolean true_false,
  metadata.platform device_type
FROM
  `sample.responses` resp
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(resp.answers) AS answer
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(answer.choices.labels) AS label
LEFT JOIN `sample.forms` forms
ON answer.field.id  = forms.id
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the query to construct the initial data

```
SELECT
  'myname@gmail.com' AS customer_email,
  CAST('2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS submitted_at,
  CAST('2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS landed_at,
  'How would you rate this product?' as title,
  STRUCT (
    [
      STRUCT('' as label)
    ] AS choices,
    10 as number,
    NULL as boolean
  ) answers,
  STRUCT (
    'other' AS platform
  ) metadata

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'myname@gmail.com' AS customer_email,
  CAST('2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS submitted_at,
  CAST('2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS landed_at,
  'What did you enjoy the most about your experience with us?' as title,
  STRUCT (
    [
      STRUCT('' as label)
    ] AS choices,
    NULL as number,
    NULL as boolean
  ) answers,
  STRUCT (
    'other' AS platform
  ) metadata

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'myname@gmail.com' AS customer_email,
  CAST('2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS submitted_at,
  CAST('2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS landed_at,
  'What other product(s) would you like to see us make?' as title,
  STRUCT (
    [
      STRUCT('Additional Designs' as label),
      STRUCT('Additional Colors' as label)
    ] AS choices,
    NULL as number,
    NULL as boolean
  ) answers,
  STRUCT (
    'other' AS platform
  ) metadata

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'myname@gmail.com' AS customer_email,
  CAST('2018-12-25 04:00:02 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS submitted_at,
  CAST('2018-12-25 03:59:07 UTC' AS TIMESTAMP) AS landed_at,
  'What color(s) would you want to see?' as title,
  STRUCT (
    [
      STRUCT('Green' as label)
    ] AS choices,
    NULL as number,
    NULL as boolean
  ) answers,
  STRUCT (
    'other' AS platform
  ) metadata
```

Then your query would be

```
WITH joined_table AS (
    SELECT
        customer_email,
        submitted_at,
        landed_at,
        title,
        answers.choices answers_choices,
        answers.number score,
        answers.boolean true_false,
        metadata.platform device_type
    FROM `sample.responses` resp
    LEFT JOIN `sample.forms` forms ON resp.answers.field.id  = forms.id
)

SELECT 
    customer_email,
    submitted_at,
    landed_at,
    title,
    unnested_answers_choices.label as answer_choices,
    score,
    true_false,
    device_type
FROM joined_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(answers_choices) AS unnested_answers_choices
```